# Zuul proxy forwarding error because of timout

Tags: netflix-zuul

I have created a zuul api gateway. It is throwing timeout for long running request.

Below is the log
    2018-11-02 18:47:55.593 ERROR [SERVICEGATEWAYV1,0f51d4fe1d259272,9a68568956eacd45,false] 17880 --- [nio-9091-exec-6] c.i.s.gateway.filter.error.ErrorFilter   : Service is not available {}
    2018-11-02 18:47:55.598 DEBUG [SERVICEGATEWAYV1,0f51d4fe1d259272,9a68568956eacd45,false] 17880 --- [nio-9091-exec-6] c.i.s.gateway.filter.error.ErrorFilter   : Debug :

```
org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.util.ZuulRuntimeException: com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.run(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:116) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.runFilter(ZuulFilter.java:112) ~[zuul-core-1.3.0.jar!/:1.3.0]
        at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:193) ~[zuul-core-1.3.0.jar!/:1.3.0]
        at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.runFilters(FilterProcessor.java:157) ~[zuul-core-1.3.0.jar!/:1.3.0]
        at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.route(FilterProcessor.java:118) ~[zuul-core-1.3.0.jar!/:1.3.0]
        at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulRunner.route(ZuulRunner.java:96) ~[zuul-core-1.3.0.jar!/:1.3.0]
        at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.route(ZuulServlet.java:116) ~[zuul-core-1.3.0.jar!/:1.3.0]
        at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.service(ZuulServlet.java:81) ~[zuul-core-1.3.0.jar!/:1.3.0]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:157) [spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController.handleRequest(ZuulController.java:44) [spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50) [spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) [spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) [spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843) [spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110) [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.TraceFilter.doFilter(TraceFilter.java:164) [spring-cloud-sleuth-core-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106) [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_181]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_181]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]
Caused by: com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.handleException(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:189) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:164) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.run(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:111) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        ... 67 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException: PassengerService timed-out and no fallback available.
        at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$22.call(AbstractCommand.java:819) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar!/:1.5.12]
        at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$22.call(AbstractCommand.java:804) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar!/:1.5.12]
        at rx.internal.operators.OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction$4.onError(OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction.java:140) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onError(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:87) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onError(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:87) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
        at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$DeprecatedOnFallbackHookApplication$1.onError(AbstractCommand.java:1472) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar!/:1.5.12]
        at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$FallbackHookApplication$1.onError(AbstractCommand.java:1397) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar!/:1.5.12]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onError(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:87) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
        at rx.observers.Subscribers$5.onError(Subscribers.java:230) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeThrow.call(OnSubscribeThrow.java:44) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeThrow.call(OnSubscribeThrow.java:28) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
        at rx.internal.operators.OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction$4.onError(OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction.java:142) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onError(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:87) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onError(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:87) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
        at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$HystrixObservableTimeoutOperator$1$1.run(AbstractCommand.java:1154) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar!/:1.5.12]
        at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContextRunnable$1.call(HystrixContextRunnable.java:45) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar!/:1.5.12]
        at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContextRunnable$1.call(HystrixContextRunnable.java:41) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar!/:1.5.12]
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.hystrix.SleuthHystrixConcurrencyStrategy$HystrixTraceCallable.call(SleuthHystrixConcurrencyStrategy.java:188) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.0.RELEASE]
        at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContextRunnable.run(HystrixContextRunnable.java:61) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar!/:1.5.12]
        at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$HystrixObservableTimeoutOperator$1.tick(AbstractCommand.java:1159) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar!/:1.5.12]
        at com.netflix.hystrix.util.HystrixTimer$1.run(HystrixTimer.java:99) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar!/:1.5.12]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_181]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_181]
        ... 1 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
        at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand.handleTimeoutViaFallback(AbstractCommand.java:997) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar!/:1.5.12]
        at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand.access$500(AbstractCommand.java:60) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar!/:1.5.12]
        at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$12.call(AbstractCommand.java:610) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar!/:1.5.12]
        at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$12.call(AbstractCommand.java:601) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar!/:1.5.12]
        at rx.internal.operators.OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction$4.onError(OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction.java:140) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
        ... 16 common frames omitted
```

Below is my application .yml.

```
    server:
  session:
    timeout: 99000
  port: ${service.gateway.server.port}


configuration:
  service:
    name: ${configuration.service}
  serviceURL:
    metadata: serviceUrl

eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://${eureka.server.hostname}:${eureka.server.port}/eureka
      hostname: ${eureka.server.hostname}
    register-with-eureka: false

ribbon:
  ConnectTimeout: 990000
  ReadTimeout: 990000    

zuul:
  host:
    socket-timeout-millis: 990000
  prefix: /api
  routes:
    service:
      path: /as/**
      service-id: ${auth.service}



logging:
  level:
    com.iag.service.gateway: DEBUG
    com.netflix.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerContext: DEBUG
  path:
    log
  file:
     ${logging.path}/serviceGatewayServiceLog.log

spring:
  application:
    name: ${service.gateway.service.name}
  profiles:
    active: local 

hystrix:
  command:
    default:
      execution:
          isolation:
             thread:
                timeoutInMilliseconds: 990000
      circuitBreaker:
        enabled: false
        requestVolumeThreshold: 3
        sleepWindowInMilliseconds: 5000
        errorThresholdPercentage: 50
```

I have tried lot of things but not succeeded
Any help will be highly appreciable.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I applied the below in both Zuul and the underlying application and it worked fine for me.

```
ribbon:   
   ReadTimeout: 300000
```

FYI: I use Zuul v1.4.x running on Sprint Boot v1.5.x.